# AJAX - Refresh page after form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I wanted to know if this is the correct way to update my website after submitting a form because sometimes it works for me and sometimes it doesn't, I have to give f5 (update manually).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frmLostTime').submit(function(){
    var datoss=$('#frmLostTime').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"SendLostTime.php",
        data:datoss,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                setTimeout(function() {
                   window.location.reload();
              },0);
            }else{
                alert("Fallo al enviar la peticion.");
            }
        }
    });
}); });
```

That is my doubt ... because when I send data that I fill in a form, it is not updated in the table where I show it ...
Sometimes I have to give an f5 to see them updated in a table, the form is filled in a modal ... and I send it to that ajax

Comment: Surely `window.location.reload()` defeats the whole point of using Ajax in the first place?

Comment: Zach Lee @CD001 - why even?

Comment: Hi, the setTimeout function is useless and you can remove it.
Having said that, to better understand you should check your browser's response and check for errors or if the script crashes or the answer comes slowly

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the whole point of using Ajax is to dynamically update a server resource (e.g. summat in the database) and the page display *without* refreshing the entire page ... otherwise you might as well just POST a form normally, yes?

Comment: I was agreeing with you @CD001 ;-)

Comment: What data is not updated and works only when you press F5 ? are they images ? you need to give more information

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Aaaaaaah the Zach Lee <-> Exactly reference went right over my head, \*ahem\* :D

Comment: OP if you want the page to refresh *get rid of* the AJAX function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Guys, he has problem with caching, even if he submitted the form normally, *sometimes* the data is not updated without F5. If this is the case, you need to change a variable on the images links when you update them, like the hash of the new image file or the timestamp, `/images/profiles/123.jpg?hash=123456789abcdefg`

Comment: As I have been given cases on external computers in which to add a record and it is not reflected in my table, I have to give F5 to be able to see the new record reflected in the table.

My computer is the server ... I have rarely been given this error but on external computers yes, maybe it can be the response time as they comment here.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing the preventDefault in your submit function, remember that when you submit a form, the page is 'reloaded' in the browser, sometimes it could be slow and the jquery code can be executed but the many of times the 'reload' via submit is very fast and your submit function will not executed.

And try to reload using location.reload

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#frmLostTime').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var datoss=$('#frmLostTime').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"SendLostTime.php",
            data:datoss,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    location.reload();
                }else{
                    alert("Fallo al enviar la peticion.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP WANTS to reload. This makes your answer useless to him.

Comment: @JayBlanchard why is useless?

Comment: The OP is already using AJAX,, I'm preventing the submit before the data has been sent, but when the AJAX success function is called, the reload of page is send it